# How can I express a multi-line regex in assertRegex in Python 3?

Tags: python, regex, unit-testing, python-3.x

I'm using the [assertRegex() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegex) from the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) library in Python 3.4. It only takes two relevant parameters: the text to match against and the regex. The seems to prevent me from expressing any regex-related constants such as [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE).

How can I construct or specify a multi-line regex and use it with `assertRegex()`? Alternatively, is there a related way of solving my problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the Python docs:

```
(?iLmsux)
```

> (One or more letters from the set 'i', 'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x'.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the corresponding flags: re.I (ignore case), `re.L` (locale dependent), `re.M` (multi-line), `re.S` (dot matches all), `re.U` (Unicode dependent), and `re.X` (verbose), for the entire regular expression. (The flags are described in Module Contents.) This is useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular expression, instead of passing a flag argument to the `re.compile()` function.
>
> Note that the `(?x)` flag changes how the expression is parsed. It should be used first in the expression string, or after one or more whitespace characters. If there are non-whitespace characters before the flag, the results are undefined.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I thought it might be something like this but couldn't find it. If you can add a link back to the relevant chunk of documentation I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: Right towards the middle [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) looks like they've added a few flags in Python 3.

Comment: For those whom the original answer was not enough - like me, this is an example:  

original: `r'^[0-9A-F]{8}$'`  
with ignore case: `r'(?i)^[0-9A-F]{8}$'`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to construct Regexp with `re.compile` ([Official Python 3 reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)). An example is

```
self.assertRegex(str1, re.compile('\\bcd '+re.escape(os.getcwd())+'\n', re.M | re.I))
```

This is useful when the expression is complex.